# Getting all Tweets from a User, after a certain date

Tags: twitter4j

You can get all tweets for a user: via the [getUserTimeline()](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/TimelinesResources.html#getUserTimeline--) method.

You can also get all tweets after a specific date: [sinceId()](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Query.html#setSince-java.lang.String-) method.

But I want to combine these two. I want to get all tweets from a certain user, but only those tweets which were posted after a given date. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you need `sinceId()`. `getUserTimeline()` returns a paginated list of `Status`es. For each status in the list, doing `status.getCreatedAt()` returns a `Date` which is a `Comparable`. You can easily compare `Date` instances with each other and determine if a `Date` occured after another `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up just using the id of the tweet, as a marker for the date. I didnt care about the date per se, but simply whether the tweet was before or after the previously loaded tweet. The docs suggest that the id is a more or less reliable indicator of recency. I.e., id 1234 is most likely to be a tweet that was posted before id 1233.

Thanks!